Expand an element's hitbox without affecting other elements
note: this didn't seem to be what I meant.
I'm making a menu bar (File, Edit, View, etc) where it would be nice if I could expand the hitbox of the menus to make it harder to let go of your currently opened ones.
Example of what i mean:

Two things I've tried:

I tried putting the elements in a ::before / ::after selector and then having the actual element act as the extra hitbox, but I wasn't sure how to make the margins and padding work.

I also tried to use an invisible outline but that doesn't change the element's hitbox.


Is there any way to implement this? ( JS is ok )

Your issue is unclear, add minimal reproducible example with some graphical description of what you really want.

@Meet Edited :)

According  to my understanding what you want is "Actual button should be small but its clickable area should me big/large/more". If this is what you want then you can achieve it with this two methods:
1. This approach will be useful when button would not contain any background-color and border. Hover around the button and you will notice the clickable area kicking in.


.testBtn1{
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<button class="testBtn1">This is button with transparent background and no border</button>



2. This approach will be useful when you want background-color & border.


.testBtn2{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

.testBtn2 p{
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
<button class="testBtn2"><p>This is button with background and border</p></button>



This are two ways. If I have misunderstood or missed something then do share. You can change padding as you need in both of options to increase and decrease clickable area.
